# Remove Item from Component[] in java

Tags: java, swing

I need to know how i can remove an item or items from a **Component[ ]** array in java.I don't see any methods to do it fast.I have to use java Arrays to achive that?

For Example:
  I have a **Jpanel** with 30 same buttons and i do this:

```
   Component[] comp = panel.getComponents();
```

How i can remove one or all the items from **comp**?

And something more if i set **comp=null**; it will clear all the items?

What i do:

i try to sort the Items of JPanel by name and i use Comparator adding all the items to comp and then after comp is sorted i add them again back to panel(All the items i sort are same buttons with different names) Is there a best way to do this?

**A picture with the code i use:**

[image: A picture]

Also the JButtons are part of app(let's say they are Tracks they have right click function and others)

Part 2:
**My main goal is to Dealocate the memory is used by Array Components[] (sometimes it big enough like 150 mbs) and after sorting i just don't need these Components anymore.I want Array Components[] to be alocated from memory by java garbage Collector.**

Comment: `Container#remove`?  How about maintaining your own list of items and removing them yourself?  There might be other components on the container...

Comment: Or maybe `Container#removeAll` if there is nothing else on the container...otherwise you'll need to do it one at a time...

Comment: you mean i have to make a linked list?

Comment: I agree with @MadProgrammer. By doing what you're doing, you're tying your program logic to its structure and are assuming that you'll never change that structure again. You're also increasing the complexity of your code and reducing its testability. Instead maintain your own collection.

Comment: @crAlex I don't know, it depends on what you're trying to do.  Generally, if you have a large number of like components (like buttons for example), it's easier to manage them in some kind of collection.  You might even consider using a `CardLayout`, I have no idea what would be useful, since I have no context to your problem...

Comment: Consider doing things differently. For instance, it might be easier to create a `List<Action>` and sort this, and then add the actions to a stable unchanging JButton grid. Or perhaps better, placing your items in a JTable and using its sorting functionality sort items for you.

Comment: Hmm, better is subjective, you "might" be able to use a "proxy" approach that returns the components in the order you want them (overriding such methods as `getComponent(int)` and the like.  You might be able to create a "layout" manager which orders the components by name, but that's a lot of work for little gain.

Comment: If you don't actually need the functionality the buttons, a `JTable` would be more efficient...

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring your questionable design, put the getComponents() value in a List where you can dynamically remove elements and it will automatically resize itself:

```
List<Component> compList = new ArrayList<Component>(Arrays.asList(panel.getComponents()));
// Let's assume compList has a size() value of 10
compList.remove(4);
compList.remove(7);
```

Comment: I have this amazing error  [The type list is not generic;it can not be parameterized with arguments<Component>].Ok i changed that to ArrayList and then uoaou i can not use Array.sort Method

Comment: @crAlex: But one can use `Collections.sort(compList)`, I imagine, isn't it!!!! Or one can simply use [JPanel.remove(givenComponent)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#remove-java.awt.Component-) or to remove all components at once, use [JPanel.removeAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#removeAll--). Once done, do call  [JPanel.revalidate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate--), after this, to make the changes visible, on the `VIEW`.